How to read an sdp file using python
I am runnig following command to forward webcam using ffmpeg to a remote IP over a cellular network
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -crf 35 -preset ultrafast -vf "eq=gamma=0.8" -f rtp "rtp://10.78.253.19:51372"

following command generate an sdp file which I can save in a txt file and its icon chane into vlc which I can run on remote desktop to play/see video
here is my sdp file view_camera.sdp
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 10.78.253.19
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.29.100
m=video 51372 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1

now I want to open and view view_camera.sdp in a python script to apply detection and different vision algorithm. How can I open do it

If it's clear text readable, just open it like any other file in Python?

You can run ffmpeg as a subprocess. It seems to support the operation.
